# Is using Laravel packages more efficient than manually implementing them?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I was wondering if using libraries in Laravel rather than manually writing code is an efficient way of implementation or not?

**Example**: if I'm using a package like SweetAlert or CKEditor?

In the manual process we do three things generally:

- Include CSS
- Include JS
- Call JS

However, if we use packages to install, it follows the whole Laravel framework [life cycle](https://laravel.com/docs/master/lifecycle).

In the case of using big or bulky libraries which require a lot of configuration like **azure saml-2, PayPal** or any other payment integration. I always prefer to use packages that have less manual implementation and more overriding methods.

For my every next project, I do this same thing. Please, do recommend to me what would be the preferable way to do things. I only care about the optimized code. I'm willing to spend more time writing code than installing libraries for every small thing.

Comment: Yeah I don't have years to build something that complex, Using framework is not the point, my focus is on using less of multiple internal queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, there are two major options to decide from - **manageable code** and **optimized code** and you can actually find a balance between them.

There are also two sides of the coin in deciding between the two options - **server side code** and **client side code**.

Firstly, put it in mind that the **server side** will *almost* always have more than enough resources to crunch your code (depending on the price you as a developer pay for these resourses). So, you may have to tilt to the side of **manageability** here. Using Laravel inbuilt libraries will be the best way of achieving this as it helps you more easily upgrade and update your code.

On the other hand, you can not always predict the amount of resourses available on the **client side** to crunch your front-end code - in fact, it's best to assume it's minimal. So, here, you have to tilt more to the side of writing **optimized front-end code** as this impacts **user experience** a lot.

You mentioned about the Laravel Request life cycle. Now, Laravel on its own is a **backend** PHP library. Even the its Blade templating engine code is all processed at the server before being served to the user. Same goes for your Laravel requests. This means that if you focus on writing non-laravel optimized backend code by yourself, the user-experience at the front end does not benefit from this as much as you would think. Also, a major disadvantage of this is that you may end up having to *rethink* and rewrite your entire code when ever you want to add a new major feature.

So here's my advice. Think more about manually writing optimized code for the front end - javascript, css, html e.t.c. At the back end, use inbuilt libraries (properly) and let the server and Laravel do all the manual labour. ;)

Comment: You are welcome @Vipertecpro. In addition,  it's always good to study and understand any feature of any framework (including Laravel ) so you can use them efficiently.  For instance, the Laravel Eloquent feature. A good understanding of it will help you write better queries that may also benefit user experience, such as in an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on want you want to integrate. If you want lots of functionality related to the module then you can add package. Otherwise you can include internal css and js. For e.g. you can use simply use window.print () by simply adding js rather than using laravel/snappy package. But including package can be helpful in composer install and update rather than updating manually in the future.